# Printing JTables from Java

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I have four JTables which for the user looks like one table. (Why four instead of one? It's a long story but we want to keep it that way) What is the best way to print these four tables, so they still look like one table?

The print() method doest not really allow us to print four tables together?

We also want to add a legend at the top with some descriptive info about the table.

Comment: I would create a tablemodel that implements a javax.swing.table.TableModel and contains the four actual tables inside and then provide it to a jtable to display it to the user. I can then print the same jtable. If it is too much work, then the alternative is to render the panel that contains the tables to an image file (it would be like taking a snapshot). I can post the code to paint almost any jcomponent to an image file if you want to go this route. You can then print the generated image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers!

We found an excellent solution! Used The Flying Saucer XHTMLrenderer for generating a html/css page. The page could then be viewed with the XHTMLPanel from the same framework and sent to Java's regular PrinterJob.